# Laravel 4 Routes Not Working

Tags: php, laravel

I did look at the other Laravel Route questions, but nothing seems to work for me.

I am trying Laravel 4.  I ran the command:
php artisan controller:make PhotoController

to create my controller.  Then I added a route in my routes.php file as such:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

When I go to localhost/photo, I see 404 Not Found.

Any ideas?  I can see the root  and /index.php, they both say "Hello World", so I know something is working.

Comment: Are you seeing the Laravel 404 page or the Apache / web-server 404 page? I'm thinking this could be a case of htaccess and/or mod-rewrite not being set up correctly. To test this, try loading localhost/index.php/photo

Comment: I'm not familiar with L4's artisan controller-maker, but does the `PhotoController` have an index function?

Comment: @MikeAnthony - yes, it will make a full resful controller with index etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to run

> composer dumpautoload

from the command line, so laravel knows the controller is there.

Answer (score -1):

you can also try this:

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```